# Play audio in Firefox browser

Tags: html, firefox, web-applications, browser

I have been struggling over playing an audio file in mozilla firefox browser over the past few days. I wrote a simple code in html

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="true">  
     <source src= "song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" > </source>
 </audio>
```

The audio works with chrome but somehow it doesn't with mozilla firefox (even with latest version 22). 
I even tried with a script as had been hinted in other forums

```
    <script src="/audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
    <script>
           audiojs.events.ready(function () {
           var as = audiojs.createAll();
           });
    </script>
```

But even this works in chrome but not in firefox. Can anyone explain the reason and also give the html code that can play an audio in firefox browser specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many others here have said, Firefox does not support the playing of MP3 files. Your best alternative is to also encode it in the OGG format, which Firefox can play:

```
<audio controls>  
   <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

If you are absolutely adamant that you only want to provide an MP3 file, then you need to use a Flash player to play the MP3 file in Firefox, although I would not recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think Firefox supports MP3 because of licensing.

Comment: That means I cannot play audio files with Firefox right? Or if there is any way then please do answer.

Comment: I would be obliged if you can elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, Firefox doesn't support MP3 ([explanation](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Mozilla-defends-Firefox-s-HTML5-support-for-only-Ogg-Theora-video-912003.html)). But you can use Flash to run mp3 though...

Comment: I would be obliged if you can please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

may this sample code helps you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<audio controls>
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

See [THIS](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all) will work with mozilla.

Comment: try on mozilla 22.0 or above

Comment: I have tried it with Mozilla 22.0 which is the latest stable version.

Comment: I think the ogg file is playing not the mp3 one... it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play MP3 of Мozilla you must use javascript api sample code for this is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="audio.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      audiojs.events.ready(function() {
        var as = audiojs.createAll();});
    </script>
  </head>

 <body>
    <audio preload="auto">
      <source src="http://cdn02.cdn.gorillavsbear.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/gorilla-vs.-bear-november-2010.mp3">
    </audio>


</body>
</html>
```

All example and download API you can find in this URL: http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/